# Convert array to json using php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm dealing with a problem when trying to convert a php array to json
This is my array:

```
$datos = array(
    'clave' => params_get('clave'),
    'fecha' => params_get("fecha"),
    'emisor' => array(
        'tipoIdentificacion' => params_get("emi_tipoIdentificacion"),
        'numeroIdentificacion' => params_get("emi_numeroIdentificacion")
    ),
    'receptor' => array(
        'tipoIdentificacion' => params_get("recp_tipoIdentificacion"),
        'numeroIdentificacion' => params_get("recp_numeroIdentificacion")
    ),
    'comprobanteXml' => params_get("comprobanteXml")
);
```

After that i'm using json_encode to create a json

```
$mensaje = json_encode($datos);
```

But i get a wrong answer

```
{
    "resp": "{\"clave\":\"50629091800\",\"fecha\":\"2018-09-29T17:23:57-06:00\",\"emisor\":{\"tipoIdentificacion\":\"01\",\"numeroIdentificacion\":\"310\"},\"receptor\":{\"tipoIdentificacion\":\"01\",\"numeroIdentificacion\":\"11\"},\"comprobanteXml\":\"PD94b\"}"
}
```

And i expecting something like this

```
{
    "resp": {
        "clave ": "50629091800 ",
        "fecha ": "2018 - 09 - 29 T17: 23: 57 - 06: 00 ",
        "emisor ": {
            "tipoIdentificacion ": "01",
            "numeroIdentificacion ": "310"
        },
        "receptor": {
            "tipoIdentificacion": "01",
            "numeroIdentificacion ": "11"
        },
        "comprobanteXml ": "PD94b"
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Code is not clear. Could you please update it to show where this **"resp"** comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `echo json_encode($datos, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES|JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)`

I guess [JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES|JSON_PRETTY_PRINT](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) will do the trick for you.